# Find specific string

Tags: python, string, character

I have data in the form of

```
str = '"A,B,C,Be,F,Sa,Su"' # where str[1]='M' and str[2]=','
```

I want to find `if "mystring" in str:` . where mystring is M, T, W or Th so on.

But, I want specific string only. i.e for `if "S" in str:` output should be none. And `if "B" in str:` should be only 'B' and not 'Be'

Comment: I really don't understand the *"`if "S" in str:` output should be none. `And if "B" in str:` should be only 'B' and not 'Be'"*

Comment: I give the award of the superscient to the ones who understood the question.

Comment: @NPE I want only specific string. In my case, 'B' is different from 'Be'. So, when I search for 'B', results of 'Be' should be excluded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> text = '"A,B,C,Be,F,Sa,Su"'
>>> 'A' in text.strip('"').split(',')
True
>>> 'S' in text.strip('"').split(',')
False
```